# How to programmatically bring the UWP app window to the front and maximize it while the window is minimized

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to bring an UWP APP window in the front and make the window is maximized.

I tried if the UWP APP window is restored, my code works fine. But if the window is minimized, the window won't be show and still keep in minimized status.

I'm using `FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Demo App")` to get the window's handle. Demo App is the UWP APP's display name.

Simple code as below:

```
class Program
{
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        /// Find window by Caption only. Note you must pass IntPtr.Zero as the first parameter.
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr handle = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Demo App");

            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(handle);
                ShowWindow(handle, 3);
            }
        }
}
```

Any good suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to programmatically bring the UWP app window to the front and maximize it while the window is minimized

For your requirement, We suggest launch the uwp app with [protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation). For example: `demoapp:full`. the `demoapp` is your app's launch scheme and the `full` is parameter.

We could intercept the parameter in `OnActivated` method then make the app full screen with parameter.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }
        var arg = e as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
        if (arg.Uri.LocalPath == "full")
        {
             var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
             if (view.TryResizeView(new Size { Width = 600, Height = 600 }))
             {

             }
        }

        var p = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
        p.NavigateToPageWithParameter(3, e);

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

**Update**

You could use [TryResizeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview) to resize your window

```
var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
if (view.TryResizeView(new Size { Width = 600, Height = 600 }))
{

}
```

Comment: yes, I agree with you. But for some special reason, I can't make the app in full screen. Like I need to split two applications in half screen programmatically.

Comment: So, you just want to make the window bigger, right?

Comment: actually, I already do it like you said on win8.1. For win8.1 I can simulate the keyboard send the keys "win + . + right" to bring the APP to right, and then bring another application to left. But in win10, I can't do it when the UWP app is in full screen.

Comment: yes, I just want to make the UWP app's window is maximized not in full screen.